# ASR1006 IOS upgrade with ISSU

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-asr

We were running `Cisco ASR 1006` on single `RP2/ESP` since long time but today two purchased secondary (standby) `RP2/ESP` for redendency. Now question is how do i upgrade IOS on secondary RP2?

I am confused with ISSU method, I thought ASR1006 is hardware redundant so it doesn't need ISSU, so we individually upgrade `R0` and `R1` without any ISSU, i may be wrong. can someone explain how does ISSU process work and how i can use it to upgrade ASR1006?

Comment: Cisco has some very complete documentation on this: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/asr-1000-series-aggregation-services-routers/white_paper_c11_517184.html and https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/asr1000/configuration/guide/chassis/asrswcfg/issu.html

Comment: I already read that doc and had some confusion, why we need ISSU on hardware redundant platform like ASR1006?

Comment: ISSU requires redundant hardware. It allows you to upgrade the software without rebooting the device.

Comment: Oh!! that make sense, i thought we can upgrade IOS on individual RP without ISSU.

Comment: so i only need to do this right? `issu loadversion rp 1 file stby-bootflash:asr1000rp1-adventerprisek9.02.01.01.122-33.XNA1.bin`

Comment: Without ISSU, you could load the software on each individually, but the active one would need to be reloaded while it is live. With ISSU you can install the new software and restart the standby, switch it to active, and install and reload the former active, now standby. The device continues to function the entire time.

Comment: There is a list of software that you need to update in those documents I linked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45020/discussion-between-satish-and-ron-maupin).